# How do I fix my NetBeans + PHPUnit integration?

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

On NetBeans 6.7.1 with PHPUnit 3.4.1, If I try and run the test I setup in NetBeans it errors out and can't execute the test, here is the output:

```
PHPUnit 3.4.1 by Sebastian Bergmann.

The --log-xml option is deprecated, please use --log-junit instead.

Argument #1 of PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader:checkAndLoad() is no existing file
```

The test runs fine if I run it from the command line, just not from inside NetBeans.

This is the same error you get if you pass a bad path or file to the phpunit tool. 
And NetBeans is passing a depreciated flag too..

So my question, is there a setting somewhere that I can fix this?
Does this work in NetBeans 6.8M2?

Thanks,

-Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try downgrading PHPUnit to version 3.3.9. I don't think you can do that via the PEAR channel, but there are instructions for a manual installation [www.phpunit.de](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html) if you are developing on Windows. If you are on Linux your distro should have an older version available.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to 3.3.9 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the latest build for netbeans. The one I'm using is [NetBeans IDE Build 200910290252 Download](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/). It worked as advertised for running tests.