# Windows Netbeans with PHPunit, not working

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I ran into this question: [How do I fix my NetBeans + PHPUnit integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552130)

But applying the fix mentioned there does not work. Netbeans keeps saying the version of PHPUnit is too old and that I need at least 3.3.0, while I am using 3.3.9.

Screenschots:
[image: PHP Panel overview]
[image: Error]

I haven't editted anything about the files, I just downloaded the tgz, unzipped it all and put up the link.

Comment: I'd suggest running the development version of NetBeans 6.8. That worked for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to add the path to PEAR library to the include path in your php.ini, not only in NetBeans

In my case PEAR was set up under F:/php5/PEAR. So i had to add this line

`include_path = ".;F:\php5\PEAR`

to my php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

Well, NetBeans obviously does not recognize the PHPUnit's version, the "too old" sentence is misleading in this case. I guess the problem is in the PHPUnit instalation and setup, not in the version.

Did you install PHPUnit using PEAR?
Can you run some unit tests from commandline?

Another thing is, that PHPUnit classes should be available on PHP include path.

See [this tutorial](http://davidvielmetter.com/?p=1956), I guess it should help.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have installed PHPUnit from the pear channel or website. You need to install the files from phpunit.de, as Vafliik already mentioned. Then, there should be a phpunit.bat in your php install folder. That is the one you need. Also make sure the folder where PEAR is installed is in your php path. The command line PHP may use a different php.ini, check that too.

Answer (score 0):

There's another thing you can do: check that your **PHPRC** environment variable is correct.

My phpunit.bat file looks like this:

> @echo off
>
> C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\php\phpunit %*

However, when I installed a separate version of PHP on my computer using the Windows Installer package it changed my PHPRC variable to point to c:\php\ , and that somehow caused NetBeans to show the 'too old' message.

Setting PHPRC to c:\xampp\php\ and restarting NetBeans fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189359

Download latest nightly version of Netbeans:
http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nightly/

Answer (score 0):

Try running as administrator netbeans. Helped for me.